# No longer accepting questions? Then back and forth?

Tags: support, asking-questions, close-reasons, post-ban

Upon some amount of time I've been allowed to ask a question again after being barred from asking. Upon asking a question I have received no negative reviews. But yet I have been barred again. May I ask why?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can post a question once in six months even if you are under the question ban. Here is the relevant part of [the FAQ post on post ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

"If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the chance to ask *one* new one 6 months after your last question. If that question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated."

Comment: Since I am not sure what exactly this formulation means in the FAQ post, I have asked on Meta Stack Exchange: [What “positively received” means in the conditions for lifting the question ban?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/329976) Another post which was pointed out in the comments is: [When does the question ban get applied?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252046)