# Why have I been banned from asking questions?

Tags: discussion, support, post-ban

I've been banned from asking questions. But, when I checked all my past questions and answers, I've got a total of 6 downvotes. Is this enough to get a question ban? Or have I been banned due to inactivity in the past months?

Answer (score 8):

Inactivity does not matter.

Question bans are automatically performed by the system. You can find out much more through a cursory search on meta. Or you can read [this explanatory post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

In your case, I see that you have asked a total of 11 questions. Of these, 4 are closed and 3 have been deleted. Six are downvoted, 1 is at 0 score, and 4 are upvoted. On net, you have been downvoted 10 times more than you have been upvoted. This is not a good record.

Comment: In fact, one could even say that inactivity help - since even a user who is banning from asking questions can ask a new question once in six months. (Recently, [there was a discussion on this meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30406/no-longer-accepting-questions-then-back-and-forth) which was related to this.)

Comment: I have also been banned can you explain the cause of my ban too. Thanks in advance